# Why does Mahout RMSRecommenderEvaluator evaluate method sometimes results NaN?

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine

Im trying to evaluate my recommendation system using the following code

RecommenderEvaluator rmsEvaluator = new RMSRecommenderEvaluator();
double score = rmsEvaluator.evaluate(recommenderBuilder, null, model, 0.95, 0.05);
System.out.println("RMS Evaluator Score: " + score);

Some time the score is NaN.

Why does Mahout RMSRecommenderEvaluator evaluate method results NaN?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your dataset is to small to have meaningful results.